# Sharepoint Designer stripping accent

Tags: sharepoint, encoding, sharepoint-designer

I have an issue with Sharepoint Designer. Every time I put an accent in its HTML entities form: either `&#233;` or `&eacute;`, Sharepoint Designer changes it to `é` upon Check In and isn't shown when accessing the page on Internet Explorer.

Is it an encoding problem? What can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an encoding problem. What encoding do you have defined for your page. If it's not UTF-8, why so?

You can change the default encoding for *new pages* in Tools/Options/Default fonts.

You can change the encoding of an *existing page* by right-clicking the page, picking "page optins" and then in the "Language" tab change the "HTML encoding" attribute.

Comment: Thank you, it was in ISO-*something* (don't really know why). I switched everything back to UTF-8 and now it works great.